# Chaining smart contract deployments through instantiation in constructors

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

As the title suggests, I'm not sure what is considered to be good practice when it comes to deploying smart contracts that interact with each-other.

My example:
migrate contract A.
Contract A creates new instance of Contract B in constructor.
Contract B creates new instance of contract C in constructor.
Contract C created new instance of contract D in constructor.

This chained relationship is important for my contracts as they rely on the ownership structure to execute my design pattern.

When attempting to migrate contract A over in truffle I am getting:
"ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)

- Block limit:  6721975 (0x6691b7)
- Gas sent:     6721975 (0x6691b7)"

I guess my question is, is this pattern madness?

The block limit in the error scares me as I'm not sure if I will encounter this when migrating to mainnet?

Is this chaining of contracts adding to my gas costs in an exponential manner that could otherwise be avoided by using a different pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not madness. On-chain deployment patterns are one way to establish trust between separate contracts. But, you are running into a classic problem.

When a contract A deploys another contract B, the bytecode for contract B gets rolled up into the bytecode for contract A. This is so contract A knows what to do.

Reducing the size of the deployed contract is one of the reasons one might want to split logic into separate modules, but the roll-up defeats the purpose. In a chain like you describe, the total bytecode of all the contracts will end up in contract A and it might be too expensive to deploy, i.e. > 25K bytes.

A solution to this problem is to use a factory pattern. Contract B deployed by BFactory, C by CFactory and so on. Deploy the factories separately and pass their addresses to the contract that will own the deployed contracts. Use an `interface` to describe the deployment functions so the whole bytecode doesn't wind up the contract that needs the factory output.

Here's a sketchy idea to get you thinking about how it might work in your case.

```
interface IFactoryB {
  function deployB() external;
}

interface IB {
  function doSomething() external;
}

// Inheritance helps catch developer errors at compile time 
// You want to catch any difference between implementation and interface description

contract B is IB {
  
  function doSomething() public {
    // ... heavy code
  }
}

contract BFactory is IFactoryB { 

  function deployB() public returns(IB) {
    B b = new B(); // this is what tells the compiler to compile and include B
    b.transferOwnership(msg.sender); // same result as if A deploys an Ownable contract
    return IB(address(b));

  }

contract A { // does not need B's bytecode, only IB which is much smaller

  constructor(address factoryB) {
    IB b = IFactoryB(factoryB).deployB(); // this tells the compiler to include IB and IFactoryB
    // can now interact with b's functions
    // there is no reason at all to include B's bytecode in A because 
    // calls to B are always external to A
  }
}
```

In summary, use interfaces to control bytecode size and use your judgment to organize the code into separate concerns.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response Rob! The solution I ended up going with was 

A deploys B.
C deploys D where I pass in the address of B into C's constructor to complete the chain. 

I had not thought about using Interfaces however! so this is definitely something I will look into. Thanks again